# How to remove all files that are empty in a directory?

Tags: linux, shell, rm

Suppose I've got a directory that looks like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 some-user wheel 0 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 some-user wheel 257 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 some-user wheel 0 file3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 some-user wheel 212 file4
-rw-r--r-- 1 some-user wheel 2012 file5
.... more files here.
```

If it's relevant, assume that the names of the files are more random than just file#.

How do I remove only the files that are empty (meaning that the file has 0 bytes in it) in a directory, using rm and grep or sed in some form?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Sorry about that. I needed to know for a cleanup script I was writing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to run `find` with `-empty` test and `-delete` action, e.g.:

```
find -type f -empty -delete
```

The command finds all files (`-type f`) in the current directory and its subdirectories, tests if the matched files are empty, and applies `-delete` action, if `-empty` returns *true*.

If you want to restrict the operation to specific levels of depth, use `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` global options.

Comment: @Inian The GNU `find` manual points out that `-delete` "was introduced by the BSD family of operating systems", so it should be more broadly available than just on systems with GNU `find`.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Cheers! couldn't find directly on this [`POSIX`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) page, just confirmed in `FreeBSD` page

Answer (score 1):

The command is:

```
cd DirectoryWithTheFiles
rm -f $(find . -size 0)
```

Comment: This breaks for filenames with spaces.